# Logic for Blackjack Game

Tags: java, loops, blackjack

I am coding a blackjack game and I am very far through. However, I just got to the point of adding together the score after each hand (something I thought would be easy) but Aces are proving to rack my brain endlessly. Since casinos play with multiple decks, it's possible to get **up  to 21 aces** in the same hand mathematically.

How do I make a loop to go through an ArrayList of Integers called Hand which has ints which correspond to the cards that are in the hand. EX. A player hits and now has a Ace, a 5, a 2, a King, and now draws an Ace. The arraylist to represent his hand is [1, 10, 2, 5, 1]

My idea:

```
public void calculatePlayerScore()
{
    int counter = 0;
    int aceCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < hand.size(); i++)
    {
        if (hand.get(i) != 1)
        {
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            aceCount++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < aceCount; i++)
    {

      //Now that we know the regular cards
      //and we know how many aces there are
      //we should be able to loop to find the most
      //optimal score without busting, and pick the highest among those

    }
```

If anyone has an idea for this, please let me know. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: That's a very broad question for this site, and will require substantial effort for someone to answer.   See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I understand it's a bit off the norm for questions but honestly I don't know if I can ask it any more succinctly. I've never encountered a situation where numbers in my array can either be an 11 or a 1. I ask on SO as someone may have a clever method for answering this type of problem. I apologize for my subject line being so poor, if someone could edit it to: "How to count values in an ArrayList which can either be one number or another - Blackjack Game".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that only one ace can count as 11 in a hand. (Otherwise, the total will be at least 22.)

```
Calculate hand with all aces counting 1
if ( (hand total is <= 11) AND (there is at least one ace) )
      hand total += 10  // one ace counts as 11
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one ace can ever be 11. Summing a hand looks like this:

```
public int calculateScore(Hand hand) {
    int total = 0;
    bool hasAce = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < hand.size(); i++) {
        int r = hand.get(i);
        total += r;

        if (1 == r) { hasAce = true; }
    }
    if (hasAce && total < 12) { total += 10; }
    return total;
}
```

In a real blackjack game, you might also want to return the fact of whether the hand total is soft or hard also.

Answer (score 0):

IF the total of the hand is over 21 BUT one of the cards in the hand =11, then make 11 = 1.

Answer (score -1):

Take the sum of your "Hand" ArrayList, for any location that you see an "Ace" at, calculate that sum with both 1 or 11 as the additive. If your sum is greater than 21, you bust. If not, continue. If it is exactly 21, add that hand to your successes, and stop hitting.

The brute force method of solving this problem is to implement a "look-ahead" function, where you can look at your entire hand once, then calculate all the possible combinations your hand provides, including the Aces within your hand as either 1's or 11's. After you generate this list of possibilities, you can then see which possibility has the least number of cards to create the blackjack or highest hand value, and choose that possibility. It's a common algorithm problem and there are probably very efficient solutions out there for you to look at.